# Microsoft Graph API Authentication - Access token is empty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a bearer token to upload a file to Microsoft Teams.
When doing a post request to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/{tenantId)/oauth2/v2.0/token
body: 
    client_id, 
    scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/.default, 
    grant_type= authorization_code, 
    client_secret & redirect uri (https://myenvironment.com/callback)
```

**code**: I got this by doing a request to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized with error code `InvalidAuthenticationToken` and error message `Access token is empty`.

Comment: auth code flow:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which api you wanna call here, but I can show you an example. For instance, I want to call [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to upload a file on behalf of me.

Then I need to give api permission for calling this api, you can see api permission here.

[image]

Then open the browser to send a request like this

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=client_id
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.ReadWrite.All
&state=12345
```

Then you will get a code in the url, then cope the code.

```
Post: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

request header
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

request body
client_id:
client_secret:
code: copy_from_browser_url
redirect_uri:http://localhost:8080/
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.ReadWrite.All
```

Comment: The scopes were the problem. After adding the scopes you mention it worked. Thank you